# What is the Remote Access section under Installed Packages for?

Tags: unlocked-package

I was not able to find any relevant documentation that would explain what the Remote Access section under Installed Packages is for. Please see the image below for illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are third-party websites that the package is allowed to access. This access is configured as part of the installation process. These sites are accessed through flows or Apex code.